# Resizing a label inside a gridlayout?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qt-creator, qt-designer

I'm learning Qt, maybe this is easy but I can't seem to figure it out.

First, I have a file path in a QString, `myPath`. I want to load it and show it in a window.

Suppose I have a window with a label inside it:

```
QPixmap image(myPath);
ui->myLabel->setPixmap(image);
ui->myLabel->resize(image.size());
```

It works, but the on the right there is no border. I thought about fixing that with a gridlayout. I'm not sure if that's the appropriate solution however.

Anyway, that means I'd have a gridlayout in the window and then the label inside. But once I use that pice of code, the image is only as big as the gridlayout.

So, how can I have my image with some borders around it, and how can I have the gridlayout resize itself appropriately?

Comment: What do you mean by having "some borders around" your image? Can you give us some image/link to what you want to achieve?

Comment: Sort of like Java's GridBagLayout, where you can set a spacing between elements. I guess it isn't a border, just some space between two buttons for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood correctly but I believe you want some padding inside the label. That can be accomplished for example with QSS, Qt's flavor of CSS.

```
ui->myLabel->setStyleSheet("QLabel { padding: 10px; }");
```

should do the trick.